# Group by aggregate function SQL

Tags: sql

I need to group by an aggregated by count column and it's not possible on SQL. As a simple example, I have a table with events and I want to group by the count of those events.

Table
(event 1,event 2,event 2,event 3,event 3,event 4)

```
select events, count (events) 
from table 
group by events
```

the result is

```
events   count(events)
event 1  1
event 2  2
event 3  2
event 4  1
```

What I need is to know how many events occurred 1 time and how many 2 times and so on, which would give me the following result:

```
count(events) occurences
1             2
2             2
```

Can anyone suggest a way to obtain that result, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, tag your DBMS

Answer (score 1):

here is one way you can do it:

```
select 
   e.counts
 , count(*) occurences 
from (
select events, count (events) counts
from table 
group by events
) e
group by e.counts
```

Comment: This is the most straightforward way for almost any DBMS, I think